# how to append long line (like code) with symbols [)"$&...ect to existing file?

Tags: shell

I ask this question after trying all codes shared in the site about this without success,

1. I have a file that contains a very long text, all the text is in the first line only
2. I want to append long line with symbols to the end of this file, and my line look like this:

   ```
   [{\n"code":"final .net.wifi.WifiManager wifi \u003d\n "typeName":"","palette":"9","type":" ","spec":"Enable WiFi"}]'
   ```

I want to append this line that contains symbols such as `\n` and  `[{]"...`. to an existing file in the end of first line.

Comment: do you want special characters insert exactly as those are, or those should interpret to actual character like `\n` to actual newline not literal backslash-n `\n` characters? or same for unicode characters like `\u003d`

Comment: the \n is inside the line that i want append the file, this my problem, the \n always make my line separatly added in other next lines

Comment: i want to append the whole above code as its look, to the and of text in a file

Comment: Does your line contain single quotes `'`?  There is one at the end of your example  but it might by a typo.

Comment: not me who added the single quote at last, in my line there's no single quotes but the double quotes and many others symboles are there even \n and this refer to other line and break the operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your line is very complex and contains many escape characters I'd
suggest using printf "%q" that some shells such as Bash support. You
can use the following short script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -r
printf "%q\n" "$REPLY"
```

Run it and paste your line:

```
$ ./printf-q.sh
[{\n"code":"final .net.wifi.WifiManager wifi \u003d\n "typeName":"","palette":"9","type":" ","spec":"Enable WiFi"}]'
\[\{\\n\"code\":\"final\ .net.wifi.WifiManager\ wifi\ \\u003d\\n\ \"typeName\":\"\"\,\"palette\":\"9\"\,\"type\":\"\ \"\,\"spec\":\"Enable\ WiFi\"\}\]\'
```

The last line is showed in the form you can use in shell without
adding extra escape characters like that:

```
$ echo \[\{\\n\"code\":\"final\ .net.wifi.WifiManager\ wifi\ \\u003d\\n\ \"typeName\":\"\"\,\"palette\":\"9\"\,\"type\":\"\ \"\,\"spec\":\"Enable\ WiFi\"\}\]\' >> FILE
$ cat FILE
[{\n"code":"final .net.wifi.WifiManager wifi \u003d\n "typeName":"","palette":"9","type":" ","spec":"Enable WiFi"}]'
```

Comment: thanks so much bro for your hel and replying, the code look like complicated or hard for me as beginner can you tell me just what's the basic for using the last of your code 

for example where should i put this \ in my code i see it anywhere i want to know the basic of using this for i cant deal with another codes

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand what you mean at all. Write your posts more carefully..

Comment: sorry !
i mean, in your last example you have used echo command 
and in my line you use the \ \ \ \
how can i use that in another line, what is the secret of using this \ \ in the line

Comment: i mean where should i put the backslash, what i follow

Comment: As I said, you need to run `printf-q.sh` first and paste the line literally as shown in the example. The script will output the line that is properly escaped and can be used within shell. You don't have to add any extra backslashes.

Comment: aha, i understand now, i will try it now, thank you so much brother

Comment: brother help me in this please, how can i run your command, look at the output:
~$ ./printf-q.sh
bash: ./printf-q.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: Hmm, are you running this on Android? Try `bash ./printf-q.sh`.

Comment: I was running it in online terminal emulator linux, but now i installed parrot security i will try on it, i will try your command with bash in my android

Comment: Always same output problem, "no such file or directory so what i will do is to apply that on parrot os

Comment: Have you created `printf-q.sh` with contents I provided?

Comment: yes brother i tried it as you mentioned, in android and now in parrot os
when i use this command "printf-q.sh" i get message "command not found". 
and when i try this "bash printf-q.sh" i get message "no such file or directory".
how can i get the command "printf-q.sh" working ? i need package for example ?

Comment: No, you have to create a file `printf-q.sh` with the contents I provided using the editor such as `nano`.

Comment: brother didn't work with me, maybe i did mistake, but really what you shared with is the only way work for me is your way, thanks so much, i just opened this site onlinelinuxtools.com, it is tool to ecape spaces in shell and really it is working 100% as i wanted, thanks so much broooooooo

Comment: Glad to hear. Please accept this answer to let other users know your problem is solved.

Comment: yes i do, but im new in this site and confused how to do such things, can you guide me how to accept your answer

Comment: Done ! thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Use a quoted here-document:

```
cat >>file <<'END'
[{\n"code":"final .net.wifi.WifiManager wifi \u003d\n "typeName":"","palette":"9","type":" ","spec":"Enable WiFi"}]'
END
```

This appends the contents of the here-document to the end of the file called `file`.  Since the here-document is quoted, as is evident from the single quotes around the initial `END`, no expansions or filename globbing or other interpretation of the data will be done by the shell.

Comment: brother im using the command shell in android, so when i tried this code i got error can't create temporary file.
because i don't have access to file system
there's no other way to use this code  avoiding create temp ?